# Populating 2D Array with songs and rating

Tags: arrays, string, multidimensional-array, foreach

So I am trying to write a 2D array using Java that stores the names of songs and its rating in each of its slots. I have tried doing this with nested for-each loops but it doesn't work. Is there a way to store the songs that works?

```
public class Jukebox
{
    String[][] songList = new String[2][3];
    public Jukebox()
        {
            for ( String[] row : songList)
                {
                    for ( String column : row)
                        {
                            songList[0][0] = new Jukebox( "Jet Airliner" );
                            songList[0][1] = new MySong( "Slide", 4 );
                            songList[0][2] = new MySong( "Tom Sawyer", 3 );
                            songList[0][3] = new MySong( "Purple Rain", 2 );
                            songList[1][0] = new MySong( "Sing a Song", 1 );
                            songList[1][1] = new MySong( "Baba O'Riley", 5 );
                            songList[1][2] = new MySong( "Jumper", 4 );
                            songList[1][3] = new MySong( "Car Wash", 3 );
                            songList[2][0] = new MySong( "Kung Fu Fighting", 2 );
                            songList[2][1] = new MySong( "Right as Rain", 4 );
                            songList[2][2] = new MySong( "Beat It", 5 );
                            songList[2][3] = new MySong( "Bust a Move", 4 );
                        }
                }

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, what problem do you need to solve? Wouldn't the use of a HashMap be more desirable? Suppose you have 5 songs:

```
Map<String, Integer> songs = new HashMap<>();

//populate the map as
songs.put("Slide", 4);
songs.put("Purple rain", 2);
songs.put("Jumper", 3);

//iterate through the map as
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer>entry : songs.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Song: " + entry.getKey() + " rating: " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Hope this helps you.